# how to search result without caring any dot(" . ") in autocomplete box?

Tags: mysql

query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT university_name
     , state
     , university_id 
  FROM all_university 
 where short_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' 
    or university_name like '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' 
 ORDER 
    BY CASE WHEN short_name LIKE '%".$_POST['keyword']."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END 
 limit 100
"
```

when I write any university name inside the autocomplete box it show me result but not perfectly suppose when I (ccs) it show me (chaudhary charan singh university) but when I write (aks) in autocomplete box then it show nothing where I have a name of university (A.K.S university) in all_university table. So, How can I fix this issue ? please help

Thank You

Comment: REPLACE (shortname,'.','') LIKE...

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should try to remove the dots, you should allways use or appercase or lowercase:

```
$sql = "SELECT university_name,state,university_id 
        FROM all_university 
        where UPPER(replace(short_name,'.','')) like '%".strtoupper($_POST['keyword'])."%' 
             or UPPER(replace(university_name,".","")) like '%".strtoupper($_POST['keyword'])."%' 
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN UPPER(replace(short_name,".","")) LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['keyword'])."%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END limit 100"
```

Comment: it gives same result @nacho :(

Comment: @kevin try it now converting everything to uppercase